# send & receive ICMP with datalink raw socket over local interface

Tags: linux, sockets, data-link-layer

I am learning datalink raw socket programming on Linux, and I found these helpful [examples](http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html). I compiled the icmp4_ll.c, and used it to send an ICMP packet to anther computer in the same LAN. I can receive the reply from the destination computer. However, when I used it to send an ICMP packet to the local computer, that is, I set the source and destination Ethernet MAC and IP addresses to the MAC and IP address of eth0, I cannot receive the ICMP reply on either eth0 or lo interface (In Wireshark, I only noticed the ICMP request sent over eth0, but no ICMP reply on any interface.)
I think the ICMP request message is composed correctly, (otherwise the remote destination wont reply). But I don't know why the OS just doesn't reply the request. Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get a reply, the echo request is either wrong, or there's something blocking the reply elsewhere.

Comment: I was thinking this possibility, but when the same program is used to send an ICMP request to a remote computer, I can see the reply form that remote computer. The reply is missing only when the program is used to send a request to the local interface.

Answer (score 0):

**RFC 792** defined special conditions for the ICMP messages:

> - No ICMP error messages are sent in response to ICMP error messages to avoid infinite repetition.
> - For fragmented IP datagrams, ICMP messages are only sent for errors on fragmented zero (the first fragment).
> - ICMP error messages are never sent in response to a datagram that is destined to a broadcast or a multicast address.
> - ICMP error messages are never sent in response to a datagram sent as a link layer broadcast.
> - ICMP error messages are never sent in response to a datagram whose source address does not represents a unique host (**the source address
>     cannot be zero, a loopback address, a broadcast address or a multicast
>     address**).
> - ICMP error messages are never sent in response to an IGMP message of any kind. When an ICMP message of unknown type is received, it must
>     be silently discarded.

Routers will almost always generate ICMP messages but when it comes to a destination host, the number of ICMP messages generated is implementation dependent.